# I don't speak English well. Where can I get help with questions about Bitcoin?

Tags: community, forum

I'm interested in Bitcoin but don't speak English well. Where can I find more information about Bitcoin, and get help with my questions in [my mothertongue]?

*This is a canonical question to serve as a lightning rod for questions in **Russian, Japanese, Chinese, Spanish, Turkish, Arabic**<sup>[1]</sup>, or other non-English languages that we do not support here.*

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> listing languages I've already seen on Bitcoin.SE.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is **Bitcoin.org** website:

https://bitcoin.org

The site content is available in several international languages and provides a good overview of Bitcoin, and links to many helpful resources.

Answer (score 2):

[Bitcointalk](http://bitcointalk.org/)
is a forum where you can exchange with others in different languages:

There are separate forum sections for Indonesian, Spanish, Chinese, Croation, German, Greek, Hebrew, French, Indian, Italien, Dutch, Korean, Filipino, Polish, Portuguese, Russian, Romanian, Turkish and sections for a number of other languages.

Answer (score 1):

and, as this is a community driven project, and everyone can support (and you can help in the efforts on translation), have a look here:
[https://www.transifex.com/bitcoinbook/mastering-bitcoin/languages/](http://Mastering%20Bitcoin)
Andreas book "Mastering Bitcoin" has already been translated into many languages, and serves as a very good start into the matter.